# Get current transaction under @Transactional annotated method

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two transaction manager in my application, I have to execute a dynamically generated native query, for which I need to fetch Current transaction EntityManager.

Is there any way we can get the Current Transaction (created by using @Transactional annotation) entity manager?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [TransactionAspectSupport.html#currentTransactionInfo](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.html#currentTransactionInfo--) to access the current transaction.

Edit: 
Well, if you just need to access the `EntityManager` bean, you can directly inject it to your service

Comment: This returns TransactionStatus object, how can I get EntityManager bean from this?

Comment: Look at [TransactionAspectSupport.TransactionInfo.html#getTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.TransactionInfo.html#getTransactionManager--) after that. Depend on which transaction you're using, casting to the appropriate one and use it

Comment: if you just need to access the EntityManager bean, you can directly inject it to your service